# How to Perform a One-Way Send with a Custom WCF LOB Adapter

Tags: biztalk, wcf-lob-adapter

I'm trying to create a basic one-way custom WCF LOB Adapter for use with BizTalk and am implementing the `Execute` method that gets created by the Visual Studio WCF LOB Adapter SDK project Wizard.

The documentation for this method is summarized with the following comment, that appears right above the method :

```
   // Executes the request message on the target system and returns a response message.
   // If there isn’t a response, this method should return null
```

However, when returning `null`, an error is raised in BizTalk, with the following (roughly translated) message:

`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The server did not produce an appropriate response ; this may be due to non-matching contracts ; a premature end of the session or an internal error.`

What gives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the LOB adapter SDK, but the WCF adapter in BTS doesn't support [one-way services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sonuarora/archive/2007/05/28/wcf-one-way-services-and-biztalk-wcf-adapter.aspx) very well. You're best bet might be to return an empty message (i.e. void, but not one way, in a regular service contract.)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes that seems to be the correct answer. I still need some help figuring out how to return "empty" or "void" message, but that is more a concept that pertains to WCF than to the WCF LOB Adapter SDK.